# How do I determine which audio driver is used during installation?

Tags: drivers, sound, kernel, pulseaudio, alsa

I am experiencing the dreaded and all-too-common "[Dummy Output](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=dummy%20audio%20output)" audio problem. For the past three days, I have tried every "fix" on this site (and others) without success.

Rather than ask (again), "How do I fix this?," I'd like to approach this differently.

#### Background

**Device:** [Dell Inspiron 7591, Ubuntu Certified configuration](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201903-26881)

1. Installed Kubuntu 19.0. Failed.
2. Installed Kubuntu 18.04. Failed.
3. Installed Manjaro 19 for comparison and troubleshooting. Audio
   output worked, input did not. System unstable.
4. Installed vanilla Debian. Failed.
5. Installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. Failed.

The only difference between my machine and the certified machine is the kernel. (Tested: 5.0.0-1016-oem-osp1; Installed: 5.3.0-42-generic)

I installed the OEM kernel (`apt install linux-oem-osp1`) and rebooted with no success.

`hw-probe` indicates that [the card is detected](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=eafa1cb098).

The device is supported by kernel versions 4.11 and newer with the following drivers:

- 5.2 - 5.5    sound/soc/sof/sof-pci-dev.c
- 5.0 - 5.5    sound/soc/intel/skylake/skl.c
- 4.11 - 5.5   sound/pci/hda/hda_intel.c

The device is loading `snd_soc_skl` without success.

**[UPDATE]:** By suggestion, I am adding the output of `sudo lshw -C sound`:

```
       description: Multimedia audio controller
       product: Cannon Lake PCH cAVS
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_soc_skl latency=32
       resources: irq:17 memory:ed318000-ed31bfff memory:ed100000-ed1ffff
```

Next, I was going to try to load the oldest (and still supported) `hda_intel` driver but then I had a realization: **during installation, when booted from the USB key, there was audio output:** The drums played on launch and audible notifications played during the installation process.

A logical conclusion is to just **use that driver.**

**How do I find out what audio driver is loading during set up? Check the kernel modules in the Grub menu? Something else?**

I've already searched in the install packages to the best of my ability and didn't find anything related to audio.

I am generally very happy with this machine and I really don't want to send it back, but I will if I can't get Ubuntu installed.

Comment: You list a number of things that are off-topic, and some that don't exist. There is no Kubuntu 19.0 as no 0 month (Ubuntu releases are *yy.mm* showing release year.month). You also refer to .c program source code files as 'drivers' which they are not (drivers = kernel modules). I would use `sudo lshw -C sound` to list.hardware of class=sound to find 'driver' (or kernel module) in use; but it's one of many ways.  *FYI: Detail like Vanilla debian isn't helpful without version info*

Comment: Do you mean something like booting with an Ubuntu's  live-pendrive, installing and running `inxi -xA`?

Comment: You are correct: I was using the shorthand for the source code for the drivers provided by linux-hardware.org as a proxy.

Comment: @PabloBianchi Could you be more specific about how to accomplish what you suggest? When and how would that command be entered during installation?

Comment: After booting with a live-pendrive > _Try Ubuntu_ if the sounds works fine, you can open a terminal and `sudo apt install inxi -y && inxi -xA` the get the audio driver.